# NullPointerException onCreate Application with sugar

Tags: android, sugarorm

Manifest tag application:

```
   <application
        android:name=".util.StartApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_guard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:name">
```

My application  extends a sugar application

```
 StartApplication extends CoreApplication{...} //it is in a main module
 CoreApplication extends com.orm.SugarApp{...} //it is in a library module
```

and on oncreate i am getting a nullpointer:

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
```

some one alredy fix it?

here is my stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application br.com.egsys.guardronda.util.StartApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4641)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:91)
            at com.orm.SugarConfig.getMetaDataString(SugarConfig.java:74)
            at com.orm.SugarConfig.getDatabaseName(SugarConfig.java:19)
            at com.orm.SugarDb.<init>(SugarDb.java:27)
            at com.orm.Database.<init>(Database.java:12)
            at com.orm.SugarApp.onCreate(SugarApp.java:11)
            at com.br.mobilecore.nucleo.CoreApplication.onCreate(CoreApplication.java:56)
            at br.com.egsys.guardronda.util.StartApplication.onCreate(StartApplication.java:71)
```

Comment: If you have access, What is this at com.br.mobilecore.nucleo.CoreApplication.onCreate(CoreApplication.java:56)?

Answer (score 0):

i remove this code:

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

from my application and now all is working, but i am afraid to get back erros about multidex.

Comment: Hah.. Ok good.. I was confused with the Context, That is why I wanted you to add the application tag. Any way I am glad

Answer (score 0):

The onCreate method in Android typically looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Everything else
}
```

Try updating your onCreate method.

Comment: That`s for Activity.